# How to create an 2D array on an existing array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Suppose I have an existing array here

```
["abc", "def"]
```

I wanted to create an array with the existing elements inside that array:

```
[["abc"], ["def"]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's put every element into an array

```
a.map { |item| [item] }
```